# Designing an extension of existing android app for google glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I've been trying to research into this for awhile now. Is there a way to let my google glass access the login information from an app that I developed for an android phone? So that essentially the google glass app acts like a companion app for an existing android mobile phone app? Any resources or tutorials will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Google Glass GDK implementation does not have authentication capability, though this is an accepted issue by the Google Glass team to be corrected in the future. (See issue [176](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=176&q=authentication&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary).)

All indications are that future authentication will be handled through `AccountManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone told me as long as you know the app id, a standard android intent would do the magic. (but I havent try that yet)

Comment: can you please elaborate on that? I need to know the app id for the app I made for the android phone ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Sign in, see this library on how to get an OAuth token: https://github.com/victorkp/GlassAuth

Full disclosure: I made this library when people asked me to at the Wearables DevCon.

Comment: Are you using an in-house auth solution? If so, either implement a similar solution to the above (using www.google.com/device) or get an OAuth token on a computer/tablet/phone and display it as a QR code. Then use ZXing on Glass to get the OAuth token from the QR code.